# Oracle timestamp cast with local time zone has different results in / out DST date range

Tags: oracle, timestamp-with-timezone

While checking timestamp transformation i'm stumbling over different timezone conversion in or out DST range.
 
Knows Oracle the range from end of march to end of october? 
 
Are these results correctly?

---

```
SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM dual;
+02:00

SELECT 
TO_CHAR(CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-02-25T22:22:22+01:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS TZR') as timestamp with local time zone)), 
TO_CHAR(CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2020-04-28T20:20:20+01:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS TZR') as timestamp with local time zone)) 
FROM DUAL;

OUTSIDE_DST                 INSIDE_DST
25.02.18 22:22:22,000000    28.04.20 21:20:20,000000
```

Comment: `DBTIMEZONE` is useless and completely irrelevant for your question. What is your `SESSIONTIMEZONE`?

Answer (score 0):

Data type `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` means the time is **always** and only shown in current user session time zone, i.e. `SESSIONTIMEZONE`

Your statement

```
SELECT 
   CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-02-25T22:22:22+01:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS TZR') as timestamp with local time zone), 
   CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2020-04-28T20:20:20+01:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS TZR') as timestamp with local time zone) 
FROM DUAL;
```

is actually equal to

```
SELECT  
    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-25 22:22:20+01:00' AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE, 
    TIMESTAMP '2020-04-28 20:20:20+01:00' AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE  
FROM DUAL;
```

Values are returned in current user session time zone, there is nothing wrong with it. `+01:00` means always 1 hour ahead UTC, no matter if DST is active or not.

Your `SESSIONTIMEZONE` is most likely a region name like "continent/city". Try to set your session time zone for example to

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '+02:00';
```

then the result will be all in `+02:00`

You can interrogate Daylight-Saving times with `TZD`, for example:

```
SELECT  
    TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2018-02-25 22:22:20+01:00' AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE, 
           'yyyy-dd-mm- hh24:mi:ss TZD') AS ts1,
    TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2020-04-28 20:20:20+01:00' AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE, 
           'yyyy-dd-mm- hh24:mi:ss TZD') AS ts2
FROM DUAL;

TS1                              TS2                                                                        
-------------------------------  --------------------------------------------
2018-25-02- 22:22:20 CET         2020-28-04- 21:20:20 CEST                                                  

1 row selected.
```

The first time has no daylight saving (i.e. winter-time), the second one does (i.e. summer-time)

Comment: select  SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual; 
Europe/Berlin

Comment: Thanks for answers, but this does not explain, why the hour value for the first term is unchanged in result and the hour value in the second term is incremented by one.

Comment: I've read a bit in the meanwhile...
It seems, that Oracle use a rule set to calculate the dst date range. 
Unfortunately is this a binary file :-(.
-- ORA_TZFILE -- SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file; --
./oracore/zoneinfo/big/timezlrg_14.dat

Comment: @m_quadrat, I don't understand what your problem is. Oracle inherits daylight-saving time rules from [IANA - Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). If you like to get the rules, you can download from their home page. Provided you installed the latest version of timezone file `timezlrg_xx.dat` you can really trust the Oracle output.